# jQuery val() Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .val() to set the values in HTML. My code is like this:

```
function first(){
var a=1;
$("#pg_textbox").val(a);
}
```

Now this code sets vales in my hidden HTML id 'pg_textbox':

```
<input type="hidden" id="paging_textbox">
```

On the second function call, it is like this:

```
function secound(){
var b=2;
$("#pg_textbox").val(b);
}
```

Now when I use:

```
$("#pg_textbox").val();
```

to get the value of  '#pg_textbox' i am getting output is

```
2
```

It is replacing the values. I want my output like:

```
1,2
```

How can I get this output without replacing the value?

Thanks.

Comment: `$("#pg_textbox").val($("#pg_textbox").val() + ',' + b);`. Please read some books or tutorials on the basics of Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: All this anonymous downvoting... How is that encouraging him to learn? Feels like Stack Overflow Elitism.

Comment: Don't fully understand the downvoting either. It is a clear, easily answerable question with all the relevant information in place. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `.val(b)`, you do reset the entire value of the textbox. Calling `.val()` will only retreive what's in the textbox, it has no recollection of past values.

You'll need to update your setter:

```
$('#pg_textbox').val( $('#pg_textbox').val() + ',' + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if there's a value already, if there is, concatenate the values...

```
var newVal = 2;
var prevVal = $("#pg_textbox").val();
if (prevVal == '')
{
  $("#pg_textbox").val(newVal);
}
else
{
  $("#pg_textbox").val(prevVal + ',' + newVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    var b=1;
    var old_val=$("#pg_textbox").val();
    $("#pg_textbox").val(old_val+" ,"+b);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're after.

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;

$("#pg_textbox").val(a + ', ' + b);
```

Although my code is technically correct, I can't imagine any practical application for it. Since you want to output some comma-separated values, it might be wiser to enter your values in an array, *e.g.*,

```
var yourValues = [1,2],
    output = yourValues.toString();
$('#pg_textbox').val(output);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you're adding values to the input type, and don't want them to be replaced?

Well here's what you need to do then.

You need to make another hidden input type which will store the sum.

```
<input type="hidden" id="backup"/>

function first(){
var a=1;
$("#pg_textbox").val(a);
$("#backup").val(a);
}

function second(){ // Your second function
var b=1;
var sum = $("#backup").val()+b;
var old_val = $("#pg_textbox").val();
$("#pg_textbox").val(old_val+','+sum);
}
```

Also, you can continue this series with third, fourth, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Update this:

```
var b=2;
$('#pg_textbox').val( $('#pg_textbox').val() + ',' + b);
```